# iterator pointer is moving unexpectedly inside a list

Tags: java, list, iterator

I have an static method to traverse a list. However, the pointer is not moving in the positions sequentially, becuase when executing the following code, I only print the value 5. What could be the issue?.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> prueba = new ArrayList<Integer>(6);
        
        prueba.add(1);
        prueba.add(2);
        prueba.add(3);
        prueba.add(4);
        prueba.add(5);
        prueba.add(6);  
        
        Utilities.toTraverse(prueba); 
    }

}

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Utilities{

    public static <E> void toTraverse(List<E> lista) {
        
        Iterator<E> it = lista.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            E obj = it.next();
            System.out.println(obj);
        } 
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce your problem and get the whole list as output](https://ideone.com/59ZXT2).

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS thanks, you are right, executions works fine, this happens when I do debug. What could be the issue?

Comment: I have found the root cause: this happens once I click on Expressions window, why is the reason for that?.